# C++: How could I use the ICU to get the current time by given timezone offset?

Tags: c++, timezone, icu

I would like to use the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) to obtain the current time by given timezone offset (also need to calculate the daylight saving), I've tried below codes, but the snext function return NULL, the ICU library version is 6.1, CentOS 7.6 64 bit + gcc 6.4.1.

```
timezoneOffset = 1; //(UTC + 1)

UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
U_ICU_NAMESPACE::UnicodeString dateReturned, curTZNameEn, curTZNameFr;

int32_t stdOffset = 0;
int32_t dstOffset = 0;
//  
// Create a Calendar to get current date
U_ICU_NAMESPACE::Calendar* calendar = U_ICU_NAMESPACE::Calendar::createInstance(success);
if (!calendar)
{
    return;
}

success = U_ZERO_ERROR;

UErrorCode ec;
std::string errorName;

int32_t rawOffset = timezoneOffset * 3600 * 1000;
U_ICU_NAMESPACE::StringEnumeration* se = U_ICU_NAMESPACE::TimeZone::createEnumeration(rawOffset); // Obtain timezones by GMT timezone offset
if (se)
{
    auto next = se->snext(ec);
    if (next && ec == U_ZERO_ERROR)
    {
        U_ICU_NAMESPACE::TimeZone *tzWest = U_ICU_NAMESPACE::TimeZone::createTimeZone(*next);
        if (tzWest)
        {
            UDate curDate = calendar->getNow();
            tzWest->getOffset(curDate, false, stdOffset, dstOffset, success);
            if (U_SUCCESS(success))
            {
                timezoneOffset = (stdOffset / (1000 * 60 * 60) + dstOffset / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        errorName = u_errorName(ec); // The error name is "bogus error"
    }

    delete se;
}

delete calendar;
```

Comment: I don't know about the `ICU` library but it may be worth considering using the timezone library that is soon going to be part of the `C++` standard: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 3):

From [the ICU documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1TimeZone.html#aafb457e44cbce8b88500039f4f62c2ad):

> There may be several times zones with the same GMT offset that differ in the way they handle daylight savings time. For example, the state of Arizona doesn't observe daylight savings time. If you ask for the time zone IDs corresponding to GMT-7:00, you'll get back an enumeration over two time zone IDs: "America/Denver," which corresponds to Mountain Standard Time in the winter and Mountain Daylight Time in the summer, and "America/Phoenix", which corresponds to Mountain Standard Time year-round, even in the summer.

In other words, you *can't* calculate daylight saving time properly if all you have for input is an offset.  Many different zones may share this offset, some may use it at standard time, some may use it at daylight time, and some may use it all year long.

Also understand that different parts of the world use DST differently.  Some start earlier or later than the US, and some don't use it at all.  Those that use it in the Southern hemisphere are usually on winter time while the Northern hemisphere is on summer time, and vice versa.  One time zone only switches by 30 minutes instead of the usual 60.  There is no single worldwide implementation of DST.

In your code, you are creating an enumeration of zones that use the given offset during standard time (or all year), but you are only examining the first item of the enumeration.  There are no assurances that the first item is the correct one to use.

The best you could do would be to get the current time for the offset that you have, and you don't really need ICU to do that.

Comment: No worries. Leave it open. Maybe someone else will provide a more direct answer with code sample. Just wanted to make sure you knew the challenges here are less technical and more geopolitical. 